# How to reveal missing events with KSQL?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

We'd like to analyze heartbeat data with **ksql** in kafka to create warnings about dead daemons.

Available Topics/Tables

1. A ping topic is periodically (every n seconds) populated with ping events. It's intended to trigger the health check.
2. A list of daemons
3. A continuous stream of heartbeats

```
CREATE STREAM ping(
     ping_timestamp    BIGINT
) WITH(KAFKA_TOPIC='ping', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON', PARTITIONS=1, TIMESTAMP='ping_timestamp');

CREATE TABLE daemons(
        DAEMON_ID    VARCHAR,
        CATEGORY VARCHAR
) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='daemons', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON', PARTITIONS=1, KEY='DAEMON_ID');


CREATE STREAM heartbeats(
        DAEMON_ID    VARCHAR,
        HB_TIMESTAMP BIGINT,
        MSG VARCHAR
) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='heartbeats', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON', PARTITIONS=1, TIMESTAMP='HB_TIMESTAMP', KEY='DAEMON_ID');
```

**How can we create a stream with warn events about daemons for which no heartbeat was received in a 15m window?**

Intended workflow

1. Outer join `ping` with `daemons` on NULL or dummy column to create a ping for every daemon.
2. Left join the result from (1) with the `heartbeats` using a tumbling 15min window.
3. Aggregate and filter the result (2) for pings for which no heartbeats were received.

However, this does not seem possible with ksql because it does not allow for the combinatorial join needed for (1) because of its [partitioning requirements](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/partition-data.html#partition-data-to-enable-joins)

Comment: I'm not sure about ksql, but first thought is "word count" over a 15 minute window. At the end of the window, emit the count of the heartbeats.

Comment: Unfortunately not every daemon will emit the same number of heartbeats and also the rate will differ. So a simple counting approach can't work. The question is about how to use ksql (if possible) to detect that a daemon has died.

Comment: Why does it matter if the rate differs? If you have a 15 minute sliding / tumbling window, counting all events, you either get 0 or more than that. In the event of a positive number, you know it has not died. Or I am missing something?

Comment: This won't work afaik because tumbling window aggregation won't emit anything if there is no input event, i.e. there won't be any bins with 0 counts. That's why we thought about using a ping trigger. For an example see https://gist.github.com/holgerbrandl/39e0cb2639273f7360aed8a6e252f638

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a table of the `heartbeats` stream that tracks the last heartbeat received per daemon:

```sql
CREATE TABLE LAST_SEEN AS
   SELECT 
    DAEMON_ID, 
    LATEST_BY_OFFSET(HB_TIMESTAMP) AS HB_TIMESTAMP,
    LATEST_BY_OFFSET(MSG) AS MSG
   FROM heartbeats
   GROUP BY DAEMON_ID;
```

The you can join this to the daemons table, with a filter to remove any daemons that have responded in the last 15 minutes, giving you a table of dead daemons:

```sql
CREATE TABLE DEAD_DAEMONS AS
   SELECT D.DAEMON_ID AS ID
   FROM DAEMONS D LEFT JOIN LAST_SEEN LS
     ON D.DAEMON_ID=LS.DAEMON_ID
   WHERE (CURRENT_TIME() - LS.HB_TIMESTAMP) > 900000;
```

Note: `CURRENT_TIME` doesn't exist as a function in ksqlDB yet, so you'd have to cut your own, but that would be trivial.